# Oracle Trigger after insert with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, conditional-statements, insert-into

I am new to PL/SQL programming and i've been task to create a simple trigger; see code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  TRG_ACCT_IDW   
AFTER INSERT   
ON ACNTGROUPS  
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO IDWORKS_HC   
(ACCOUNT,IDW_CATEGORYNO,GRTYPE)   
VALUES   
(:NEW.ACCOUNT,:NEW.GROUP_,:NEW.TYPE)   
WHERE ACNTGROUPS.TYPE = '1'  
END;
```

Everything works great without the where clause.  Can an 'after insert' trigger have a condition clause? does my code above need reformating? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`WHEN` condition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#CIHBJHFE) would be the cleanest solution.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_ACCT_IDW
    AFTER INSERT
    ON ACNTGROUPS
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.TYPE = '1')
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO IDWORKS_HC   
    (ACCOUNT,IDW_CATEGORYNO,GRTYPE)   
    VALUES   
    (:NEW.ACCOUNT,:NEW.GROUP_,:NEW.TYPE); 
END;
```

Do not put a colon (:) before the correlation name `NEW`, `OLD`, or `PARENT` in the `WHEN` condition.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  TRG_ACCT_IDW   
AFTER INSERT   
ON ACNTGROUPS  
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN   
    IF :NEW.TYPE = '1' then
        INSERT INTO IDWORKS_HC   
        (ACCOUNT,IDW_CATEGORYNO,GRTYPE)   
        VALUES   
        (:NEW.ACCOUNT,:NEW.GROUP_,:NEW.TYPE); 
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: do I need to put a 'then' exclusion so i can ended properly? kept getting  'command not properly ended','encountered the symbol ;, when expecting if'

Comment: @dw1977 - it was missing a semicolon at the end of the insert statement: `... , :NEW.TYPE);`. Also what datatype is your `TYPE` column? If it's a number then compare it to the number `1`, not the string `'1'`.